# Minecraft 1.9.2 Coordinate Plugin with Clipboard

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

How can I copy some Text form a Message form server to player to the players Clipboard.

The Plugin gives this message out when the player write /coordcopy, the question now is how can i copy this Message to the Clipboard of the player?

Comment: Next time, i suggest you to just google before asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = "This text will be copied into clipboard when running this code!";
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
```

Thats how you copy a String to the clipboard.

But that doesn't work with a plugin, since you cannot access the client.

Comment: okey thank you, is there a posibility to make this like an link in the chat, so they can copy it to the clipboard through that?